# Passing innerHtml with inline styles (Angular 10)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am attempting to pass through html with inline styles as a variable to an angular component.

```
var htmlValue = "<div style="margin-left: 13px; font-size: large;" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
    Need Help?
  </div>"
```

However the inline style is removed when rending the code on the component.

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlValue"></div>
```

Renders as:

```
<div>
  <div>
    Need Help?
  </div>"
</div>
```

Is there a way to stop this from happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to utilize the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer). With the sanitizer injected in the constructor, your htmlValue assignment would be updated to the following.

```
var htmlValue = this.sanitizer
    .bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<div style="margin-left: 13px; font-size: large;" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
    Need Help?
  </div>")
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vvqray?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example.

**WARNING**

Angular stripping out the styles, etc initially is due to safety concerns, so do this cautiously. This should be used only when you can trust the html being injected. If the html is something that ultimately comes from user input, then this should be done very judiciously as the user could utilize this to inject unsafe code into your application.

Comment: i have same error. but my content is being fetched from api. how can i handle this.

Comment: @azhar, you will need to show some code. This should work for you as well.